# analysis of randomized select. algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Someone please explain me the meaning of the line:

> The procedure randomized select is equally likely to return any element
>   as pivot. Therefore for each k the subarray. A[p...q]  has k elements
>   ( all less than or equal to k with probability 1/n).  After the
>   procedure randomized select all elements in preceding subarray will be
>   less than k. So what this statement actually means.
>
> From clrs sec 9.2

Comment: Which algorithm are you talking about? (I am guessing it's randomized quick sort.)

Comment: yes, randomized quick sort.

Comment: which part of the statement did you not understand?

Comment: suppose we select a pivot i, and shift all elemwnys less than  to the left side of i. then all elememts to the left sub array will be smaller than i. so how the probability. comes out to be 1/n.

Comment: Don't expect that we have read the same document as you did.

Answer (score 2):

The subarray has `n` elements, `k` of which go to the left because they are smaller than the pivot. As the drawing is random, the rank of the pivot, `k`, is any number in range `[0, n-1]`, with probability `1/n`.

You can deduce that the average length of the subarray is `n/2`, and the variance is `(n²-1)/12`.